# Port forwarding not working on router using NAT?

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a Dlink router which uses NAT and I tried several ports but every time I try to connect my server(Raspberry Pi) it says connection refused. I can’t connect to the server on the RPi itself.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from within the same LAN or outside the LAN? What public IP does the router see?

Comment: @gronostaj Currently trying to connect from the same network. I wrote “hostname -a” on the pi, it gave me a 192.168.xx.xx address, I use that address for ping/ssh/vnc into the pi on the same network.

Comment: Communication within the same network doesn't require port forwarding. It's not a problem with the router configuration. You may be using a wrong port, the service could be misconfigured or maybe you're rejected by a firewall.

Comment: @gronostaj I have turned off all the firewall settings. I am using pivpn server on the pi, to access it, there’s a port 51820 configured, so I tried port forwarding 51820 but can’t access it.

Comment: Router info and port forwarding page:   https://mega.nz/file/4zQkGbwI#6EYUiL2uyf5QEjcqUtN2nbIfxFpxeDJUfMvYvTueyuA                  https://mega.nz/file/RuQCXZyb#3VDvuqWhkhUPNgFr9Tw20oqg1o1Npuu-i_q9Hlb2duk

Comment: Please don't use external uploads, just [edit] your question and include everything relevant in there. That's your private IP, not public IP. Check if the port is actually open on the Pi (`netstat -tulpn | grep 51820`). Try connecting from outside your LAN.

Comment: @gronostaj I did that but stack wouldn’t let me, it says I need to have 10 rep points to post images smh

Comment: @gronostaj I used ifconfig.me for public ip, it’s 103.51.xxx.xx, used the command you gave, it gave back udp 0     0 0.0.0.0:51820     0.0.0.0:* and udp6  0       0:::51820      :::*

Comment: So the port is open. I'm trying to check if you're behind CG-NAT, your actual public IP as seen from the Internet won't help with this. I'll need the IP of router's WAN (public-facing) interface. If it matches your public IP, that's good, but if it's in a local range then you're behind a CG-NAT and forwarding just won't be possible. So please look for the WAN IP in router's admin panel.

Comment: @gronostaj yeah my wan ip is 172.16.xx.xx and as shown in the photos links, the subnet is 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 1):

Your actual public IP is `103.51.*.*`, but your router's WAN interface is assigned a [private range IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) `172.16.*.*`. That means your router isn't connected directly to the Internet. Instead, it's connected to another LAN, which in turn is connected to the Internet. This setup is known as *carrier grade NAT* (CG-NAT) and is used because of the shortage of public IPv4 addresses.

In such setup if you forward your ports correctly they are accessible in the ISP's LAN, but not from the Internet. You'd have to forward it again on the ISP's router, but you can't do that. So you're out of luck - you can't have an Internet-reachable IPv4 address.

Maybe you'd have more luck with IPv6, but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: What if my router supports upnp? I saw somewhere a guy with cgnat using port forwarding, he did so by enabling upnp

Comment: Also can I use ngrok or something?

Comment: @MIDAS I don't think UPnP does anything here. Its job is to forward the port automatically for you, without entering it in router's settings. Unless you can trick ISP's router to open the port with UPnP, but I don't think it would allow it. ngrok could help, yes, but IIRC you'll need the paid plan to have a fixed address.

Comment: okay I’ll try to solve this, THANKS A LOT for all the help