# I Setup a Bukkit and Spigot Minecraft server and port forwarded it but can't connect from WAN

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port, minecraft

So I setup a Minecraft server for me and my friends and I am 300% sure I port forwarded it correctly but my friends aren't able to connect to it. When I used an online tool to check wether i have setup the port forward correctly, it says the port is closed. My local IP is static, I've tried disabling firewalls of the router and computer, and restarted after the port forward setup. I have a 5G connection router (HUAWEI 5G CPE MAX). These are all the settings:

[ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v35at.png)

[DHCP settings router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4uV3.png)

[Port Forward/Virtual server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQDOW.png)

[Special Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSmt3.png)

Comment: You're probably behind a CG-NAT. [Compare your WAN IP and public IP](https://superuser.com/questions/1634528/port-forwarding-not-working-on-router-using-nat/1634558#1634558).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!